# Проектирование базы данных жд перевозок

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте. Мне нужна помощь в проектировании базы данных системы пассажирских жд перевозоу. В данном случае я остановился на следующем вопросе. У меня есть сущность "Станция" и сущность "Поезд" со своими полями. Нужно связать с ними сущность "Рейс" или "Расписание". Чтобы можно было сохранять расписание поездов, проезжающих по станциям, делать поиск поезда, проходящего от станции А до станции Б. Какие варианты решений поставленной задачи самые приемлемые?

Comment: www.rzd.ru попросите, может они api вам выдадут.

Comment: Топологию веток как будете описывать? Может, у каждой станции есть указатели на соседние, и расстояние до них? Или воспользоваться графовой БД типа neo4j.

Рейс — набор пар станция-время произвольной длины. Можно расширить до "время-план" и "время-факт", последнее заполняется по мере движения поезда через контрольные точки - станции и, может, переезды.